# Updating list with files (Java swing)

Tags: java, swing, list

So, I have this code in my JFrame, and it doesn't work for some reason:

```
private void jList1MouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
        DefaultListModel jList1Model = (DefaultListModel) jList1.getModel();
        File f=new File("/home");
        File[] allSubFiles=f.listFiles();
        for (File file : allSubFiles) {
            jList1Model.addElement(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong (ignore MouseEntered event, I'll change it)? It doensn't update anything when I hover over the active this list.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: What doesn't work? Exception? no change on screen? (did you redraw/invalidate the content to trigger an UI update?)

Comment: Oh, sorry. No change on the screen. Yes, I've tried using revalidate() function.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: 1) I suspect `File f=new File("/home");` should be `File f=new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));` 2) `jList1Model.addElement(file.getAbsolutePath());` would best be `jList1Model.addElement(file);` with a [suitable renderer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336802/how-to-create-jlist-with-icon-and-text/13336902#13336902).

Comment: Try a System.out.println(file) in loop

Comment: Why do you think it should update anything on the screen? Did you add any debug code to see if your code is actually executing and if the listFiles() method returned any files?

Comment: Yes, it does return the list of files.
Okay, the problem is in `DefaultListModel jList1Model = (DefaultListModel) jList1.getModel();`, because It gives me an exception **javax.swing.JList$3 cannot be cast to javax.swing.DefaultListModel**

Comment: 1) *"Yes, it does.."*  Who are you replying to?  Tip: Add @camickr (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. 2) Error and exception output should be part of the question rather than buried in a comment.  Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33046683/edit) the question to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because It gives me an exception javax.swing.JList$3 cannot be cast to javax.swing.DefaultListModel

Don't you think that was an important piece of missing information from the question?

So basically that means you need to create your JList with code like:

```
DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
JList<String> list = new JList<String)(model);
```

Now you can dynamically try to add data to the model.