# Getting an image to appear after clicking on a JList object?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm creating a Java GUI for a user to select a playable character in a game. I have a JList to list all the different characters and I want an image of the character to appear in the JPanel below the JList when selected. What type of ActionListener do I use?

[image: Here's what the GUI looks like]

Comment: *" I want an image of the character to appear in the JPanel below the JList"* Why not have the image appear in the list entries themselves?  Like in [`FileDropList`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13336902/418556) .. *"What type of ActionListener do I use?"*  I'd use a [`ListSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html) for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know how your code is, here you have a "generic" code:

```
final JList list = new JList(dataModel);
MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        //Your load Image code.
    }
};
list.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
```