# How to display a filenames (.txt) in JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, io, java-io

This method shows only a name of file in console.

```
JTextArea area = new JTextArea(20,40);
public void readContent(){
    KreatorPytan kp = new KreatorPytan();

    File file = new File("D:\\IT\\JAVA\\zadanie\\Testy");
    File[] files = file.listFiles();

    for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(files[i]));
            if(files[i].isFile()){
                System.out.println(files[i].getName());
                area.read(reader, "File");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WyborPytan.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WyborPytan.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

I don't know why these names of files are not saving to my jtextarea. Can you help me?

Comment: Why does the title mention file **names** while the code is attempting to put the file **contents** into the text area? BTW - each time through the loop, `area.read(reader, "File");` will replace the previous content wuth the currently read content. I would expect it to show the content of the ***last*** file in the file list, when it is finished looping.

Comment: area is empty still, i don't have idea how to insert a files e.g. "quest1.txt." ; "quest2.txt" (could be without .txt" .

Comment: If you want a file **list** then a `File` `JList` is the way to go. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336802/how-to-create-jlist-with-icon-and-text/13336902#13336902) for an example.

Comment: Regarding your deleted question: You're asking a very difficult question -- you've posted a small snippet of code that we cannot compile nor run and are asking why it's not working. On inspection of your snippets, my guess is that it has nothing to do with the code that you've posted, but there's really no way for us to say for sure based on this. If you truly desire a decent and prompt solution, please consider creating and posting a valid [mre] with your question, code that compiles, runs and shows the problem, code small enough to be included with your question.

Comment: Side note: you've got an answer to this question which you've completely ignored. That's not fair to the person who tried to help you, is it?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - u have right, but I used suggestion fron Mr Andrew, the newest my post is completely different.

Comment: I've just deleted because, it was useless post.

Comment: My last comment is one of just common decency. At least post a thank you to Andrew Fomin for putting in the effort to post a darn answer. If the answer helped, up-vote it, but don't simply ignore his efforts. He (we) are volunteers.

Comment: I'm looking for suggestions, what could be reason of mistake, no full anwser. E.g: person who make a mistake in math, asking you, what did I do wrong? He didn't show his solution, so you try give him some examples right? Same I would get some suggestions. If it is impossible, skip it. Best Regards :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is reading files to JTextArea and rewriting each previous file contents with the next. So as result you will see the last file contents. If you want to get file names in JTextArea, you don't need to read file, just do smth like

```
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        area.append(files[i].getName() + '\n');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks bro for solution :) Best Regards for you :)