# Basically what i want is to display the usb directoires and a local drive directoires in two jscrollpane side by side

Tags: java, swing, file, file-listing

I have made two `JScrollPane` components. The left one shows the directories in USB and right shows the directories of a local drive. For I am able to display the complete file path as shown in first pic. But I want to display it with icons just like the way directories are displayed in any local drive on PC. [This is my designed GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrwQG.png), here is the example of what I want [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0nlt.png)

public class MainForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {
iRecordCopy obj = new iRecordCopy();

```
public MainForm() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Main From");
    setLocation(new java.awt.Point(0, 0));
    setName("mainframe"); // NOI18N

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("iRecordCopy");

    jLabel2.setText("jLabel2");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addGap(48, 48, 48)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 147, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(25, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 46, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2))
            .addGap(30, 30, 30))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 297, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 305, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 405, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
      
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>
    
    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MainForm().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public void showusb()
{
    File[] usb;
    int count = 0;
    String str;
    usb = obj.detectUSB();
          
    if(usb == null)
    {
        //USB_window.setText("No USB attached\n");
        return;
    }
    
    for (File filename : usb) {
        str = filename.toString().substring(3);
        str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 3);
        
        System.out.println(str);
        
        if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("vehicle"))
        { 
            System.out.print(filename.toString());   
            //USB_window.append(filename.getPath()+"\n");
            count++;
        }
    }
    if(count == 0)
    {
         System.out.println("No recordings found in usb");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Number of directries :" + count);
    
    
    
    //File currentDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
    JList<File> jlist=new JList<File>(obj.path.listFiles());
    jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(jlist);
    jScrollPane1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 800));
    
    setContentPane(jScrollPane1);
    
    final JLabel label=new JLabel();
    jlist.setCellRenderer(new ListCellRenderer<File>() {
        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends File> list, File value, int index,
                boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            label.setIcon(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(value));
            label.setText(value.getName());
            return label;
        }
    });   
    
}

public void showPc(File f)
{
    JList<File> jlist=new JList<File>(f.listFiles());
    jScrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(jlist);
    //jScrollPane2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 800));
    
    setContentPane(jScrollPane2);
    
    final JLabel label=new JLabel();
    jlist.setCellRenderer(new ListCellRenderer<File>() {
        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends File> list, File value, int index,
                boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            label.setIcon(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(value));
            label.setText(value.getName());
            return label;
        }
    });   
    
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: No, i just want to display files, user will not be able to select any directory. I have to copy the files in background.

Comment: Alright, then I misunterstood your question. I'll remove my comment. You could be more descriptive in your question, as to what you actually want and what is currently missing to your expected result.

Comment: i want to display file name with system icons in scrollpanel see the example image

Comment: @Umair You can use a JList with a custom renderer, the renderer can be a JLabel with Icon and text. Check the JList tutorial for details https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html

Comment: The `append(..)` method suggests(1) this is a `JTextArea`. A text aria supports only plain text. No combinations of fonts, italics, bold etc. More importantly, no embedded things like images. Use a `JList` with a `FileListCellRenderer` instead. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13336902/418556) shows what that (custom) renderer might look like. 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: BTW - the first source seen in the answer linked in my comment above uses a `JList`, but the [screenshot you link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0nlt.png) apparently uses a `JTable`. Scroll down further in that answer to see a file listing in a (tree **and**) `JTable`.

Comment: *"how can i display file icons next to file path in jscrollpanel?"* is an entirely different question to *"Basically what i want is to display the usb directoires and a local drive directoires in two jscrollpane side by side"* which is .. not even a question so much as a specification. Please roll back the edits on this **answered** question and start a new one related to the side-by-side problem.

Comment: **Also** be sure to carefully check the preview shown beneath the message posting / editing form to ensure it appears neat, and as you expect. The thing that jumps out as wrong in the above, is lack of use of code formatting. Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a short example to create a minimal JList with file icons, it displays the content of the user's home directory using the system file icons.

```
package test;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        JFrame frame=new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        File currentDir=new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
        JList<File> jlist=new JList<File>(currentDir.listFiles());
        JScrollPane scrollPane=new JScrollPane(jlist);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 800));
        
        
        frame.setContentPane(scrollPane);
        
        final JLabel label=new JLabel();
        jlist.setCellRenderer(new ListCellRenderer<File>() {
            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends File> list, File value, int index,
                    boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                label.setIcon(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(value));
                label.setText(value.getName());
                return label;
            }
        });
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson Right, edited, thank you.

Comment: is there a way to add this piece of code to my existing GUI Form?

Comment: @Umair you have to replace your USB_window (you didn't specify the class but it looks like a JTextArea), with a JList (using a DefaultListModel), when instancing the JList you must set the cell renderer as in my code. In showusb() simply clear the model and add the files there. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#creating for details.